# Better Way to Include HTML on a Dynamically Updated Page: php include() or MySQL Database?

Tags: php

I have a `<table>` that gets updated with data depending on a user choice obtained via a `$_GET` variable. Which of the two options below would be the better way to load data into that `<table>`?

1.) php `include()` would be something like...

```
<?php
$problem_id = (int)$_GET['problem_id'];
$table .= '<table>';
include('path/to/file/' . $problem_id . '.php'); //$problem_id.php would contain the <tr>'s and <td>'s that go in the <table>.
$table.= '</table>';

echo $table;
?>
```

2.) Using a MySQL database would be something like...

```
<?php
$problem_id = (int)$_GET['problem_id'];

/*
 Go to DB and get the entry which contains <tr>'s and <td>'s that
 go in the <table> and put it into the variable $table_content.
*/

$table = '<table>' . $table_content . '</table>';

echo $table;
?>
```

Is there an obvious choice here?  Pros/cons to either method?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends, and there is no reason your cant use both. Is your data located in a file or in a database? My assumption is some sort of database.Instead of storing the table structure (_<tr>s and <td>s_ )you would use the php [Query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) command to retrieve the data from your database and use the resulting array to fill your table array.

Comment: @hoss: Actually, the "data" is all of the HTML that goes in the <table> tags (<tr>s, <td>s, text, images, formatted HTML, inline CSS, etc.).  Currently it's stored in MySQL using "longtext" for the column structure.  I'm at the beginning of this project, so I have the chance to make a change now with relatively minimal work.

Comment: Is the $problem_id fixed in numbers?Or does it tend to change?If it fixed how many?Are there also update delete scenarios based on $problem_id?

Comment: What are the pages, how will new ones be created.  Do they need to be editable by non programmers.  Why are you storing full pages and not just the data, can you build the pages each time they are requested.  Pleae provide mroe info, particuarlily if you want to get bounty attention.

Comment: @TobyAllen: The "pages" are dynamically generated HTML content.  Basically I'm generating a math problem (all formatted and nice), then saving the HTML.  I will be the only one accessing/editing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that primarily depends on how large the text is, and how many you're going to have.

- If you're going to have dozens (or hundreds, or even thousands) of large, complex pages with a lot of content -- perhaps `include()` is the way to go.  You have the benefit that you can edit them directly on the file-system as well.
- If you're going to have thousands (or much more) of more simple pages, it's probably going to be more effective to go with a database.  This would additionally be a good idea if you ever want to index and search through them.

As a fairly arbitrary threshold, each file will take up a minimum of 4 kB, so if they have less content than that you're potentially wasting space with them.

In both cases, you will want to put abuse protections in for people creating a lot of content.

- filesystem-based is potentially vulnerable to me sending a query of the form `problem_id=../../../passwords.php`, as well as to having your filesystem get eaten if people can produce problems themselves.
- Database-based is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection and so on, but there is probably more out there in the way of existing solutions to that problem.

---

In the end, there are file-systems out there that are implemented as databases, and databases that are implemented as file-systems.  They aren't really all that different; they are just optimized for different things.

Comment: I will definitely end up with thousands of "entries" that will probably be in the 2-10kb range.  As for protection, I would be the only one creating files, so there's no issues there.  In this case, it sounds like the only appreciable advantage to the DB route is searching.  Does that sound right?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience a file include would be faster, but you would have to test your system to know for sure. Here is a thorough discussion of the same topic:

[What's quicker; including another file or querying a MySQL database in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166134/whats-quicker-including-another-file-or-querying-a-mysql-database-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the link Richard.  I'm more focused on what's best practice overall here, not just what's fastest.  Have any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make decision depends on each option `good` and `bad` sides

**DB Option**

*Good side* -- if you are using version controlling (E.G. `git`) and you have to give ability to `administrators` to modify that `html` templates from `admin panel` then best option for you is  **DB** because in case of **File** storage if file are modified on server via `admin panel` and in `git` at same time then you will have conflicts during server update

*Bad sides* -- `1)` you have to do more operations to take it from db and display then in **File** case. `2)` As your templates stored in db you will have additional load on database, and later if you have performance optimization question you will have to implement file caching

**File Option**

*Good side* -- `1)` it is ease for developers to modify html templates on their `IDE editors (E.G. eclipse)` then modify it in db or admin panel. `2)` file include is match faster and require less operations in code then **DB** (usually if you don't have specific case). `3)` you no need to implement file caching as it already stored in files

*Bad sides* -- 1) as i mentioned above you will have problems with `git` if you modify templates in `admin` and `git` at same time

Answer (score 0):

Your best choice if it is dynamic content is a combination of HTML5 + jQuery-Ajax + PHP + Db.

In your html page you can have a code like this:

```
<table>
    <!-- table head -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col #1</th>
            <th>Col #2</th>
            <th>Col #3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- result set -->
    <tbody id="results">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You ask the server data asynchronously with "Jquery-Ajax" and filled the empty table (#results in this example). This application is a file "PHP" connected to a DB (it can be any db engine or MySQL Database).

Answer (score -1):

MySQL is the obvious choice for me. Having a bunch of PHP documents to be included dynamically will clutter up your server. The question is do you really want to have to type up or generate new table data? You could have it all dynamically created and then inserted into the database.